# Maven and eclipse: remove JRE System Library

Tags: eclipse, maven, java

I am building a project against the [CrEme VM](http://www.nsicom.com/Default.aspx?tabid=138) Library. I want to configure maven and eclipse, to build only against this JAR. But m2eclipse "Update Project configuration" automatically adds the "JRE System library". I can fix it, by removing it in eclipse project classpath, but i want to configure it only in the pom.xml (and not checkin the eclipse settings).

I tried to do this:

```
// ... 
<dependency>
   <groupId>ch.sbb.cis-infra.mobile</groupId>
  <artifactId>vmclasses</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
// ... 
<build>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>1.3</source>
        <target>1.3</target>
        <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
        <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
        <debug>off</debug>
        <compilerArguments>
                <bootclasspath>''</bootclasspath>
            </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
```

But still, m2eclipse adds the "JRE System Library [JRE_1.3]".

Compilation on command line is correct, but in eclipse I can't see compile problems. 
**How can I remove the JRE in eclipse using the pom.xml configuration?**

(Eclipse Helios SR2, m2e plugin 0.12.1)

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO (I'm not sure) JRE container in Eclipse is because of Java nature of the project, not the Maven integration. Try to disable Maven nature of the project and JRE will be still there. If you have Maven-managed Java project (and your POM says that) Java nature in Eclipse is enabled causing JRE to be attached to the project.